# Countable state Markov chain with multiple transitions

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory

I'm searching for hints on how to analyze the following Markov chain. I can solve for the steady state probabilities numerically by using a finite transition matrix. However, I would like to have an analytical result.

For the special case of only transitions to the adjacent states (birth death process) I have succeeded in using the reversibility property. For this extended case, however, I'm missing a starting point.

[image: Markov chain]

The Markov chain continues after state "4" to infinity.

EDIT:
The transition matrix $P$ is given by
\begin{equation}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{0,0} & p_{0,1} & p_{0,2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
p_{1,0} & p_{1,1} & p_{1,2} & p_{1,3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
p_{2,0} & p_{2,1} & p_{2,2} & p_{2,3} & p_{2,4} & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & p_{2,0} & p_{2,1} & p_{2,2} & p_{2,3} & p_{2,4} & 0\\
0 & 0 & p_{2,0} & p_{2,1} & p_{2,2} & p_{2,3} & p_{2,4} \\
&&&\vdots&&&&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with a repeating pattern from the third row on. $\pi_v=\sum_{w=0}^\infty p_{w,v}\pi_w$ should hold for the elements $\pi_v$ of the steady state vector.

Comment: As a first step, can you write down the probability transition matrix for this chain?

Comment: @Gareth I have edited my original answer to include the transition matrix. I was trying $p_{i,j}\pi_i = p_{j,i}\pi_j$ previously but I don't think this is a correct approach because it neglects transitions to not neighbouring states. Another idea that I have is a decomposition of the Markov chain into 2 simple chains and then combining the results but I have not fully thought this out.

Comment: Got something from the posted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $x\geqslant4$, $$\pi_x=p_{2,4}\pi_{x-2}+p_{2,3}\pi_{x-1}+p_{2,2}\pi_{x}+p_{2,1}\pi_{x+1}+p_{2,0}\pi_{x+2},$$ hence the generating function $$\Pi(s)=\sum_{x\geqslant0}\pi_xs^x,$$ solves the identity $$\Pi(s)=(p_{2,4}s^2+p_{2,3}s+p_{2,2}+p_{2,1}s^{-1}+p_{2,0}s^{-2})\Pi(s)+s^{-2}R(s),$$ for some polynomial $R(s)$ of degree at most $5$, in particular, $$\Pi(s)=\frac{R(s)}{s^2-p_{2,4}s^4-p_{2,3}s^3-p_{2,2}s^2-p_{2,1}s-p_{2,0}}.$$ From here, factor the denominator, decompose the fraction into simple elements, and expand each as a series in $s$, to recover each $\pi_x$ as the coefficient of $s^x$ in $\Pi(s)$.

Comment: Factoring the denominator seems quite complicated. I have trouble understanding the role of $R(s)$. Does it have something to do with the first three columns? I probably need some reading on generating functions but maybe you can already elaborate some more. Maybe $p_{2,4}+\cdots+p_{2,0}=1$ can be put in use. At least it shows that $s=1$ is a zero of the denominator. It should also be a zero of $R(s)$.

Comment: Yes the simplest approach is to factor the denominator, $R(s)$ involves the first entries of the matrix, and $R(1)=0$. For asymptotics of $\pi_x$ when $x\to\infty$, the largest root of the denominator suffices.

Comment: It still looks intimidating. With your approach the problem presents itself as finding a formula for a recurrence without exploiting properties of the Markov chain and it does not seem to have a simple solution. I think your answer answers the original questions regarding hints although I have not been able to put it to use yet.